# Moshi: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $

Tags: android, json, kotlin, moshi

So I am setting up a Retrofit API call with a custom parsing file and having that file sent to a Room DB that I have set up. I have been running to a problem with the repository, where I'm getting the error "Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $". I tried casting the String extension as an List in my interface, but the JSONObject won't accept it.

Here's the interface

```
interface InfoCollections {
    @GET(ENDPOINT)
    suspend fun getInfoService(): String
}
```

The function in the Repository

```
 suspend fun fetchInfo(){
        val response = Networking.moshiNetworkingServices.getInfoService()
        val feeds = parseJsonInfoResults(JSONObject(response))
        infoDao.insertAll(*feeds.toTypedArray())
    }
```

If anyone needs more information, please let me know. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I belive you've declared moshi as json converter at Retrofit config, so the Retrofit call should give you the json, why are you again trying to parse json?

Comment: I'm doing that because I wanted certain information from the API, instead of the entire API object call. Plus it acts as a mapper to send the JSON into a Domain Layer (Data Class Model).

Comment: Rather than returning a String, you can declare the return type as Response<YourJsonObject> and create a class with json fields in it, (you can use this https://www.json2kotlin.com/) also while creating retrofit instance you need to add MoshiConverterFactory. Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: I took your advice and switch the way I was calling the API. It seems to be working, but now I have a different problem. But that's a story for another time. Thanks for the help.